# Global functions and capturing values in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, scope

Swift documentation says that closures and nested functions can capture values while global functions can not. Why then this is not a compilation error (in fact it looks like the global funciton myFunc() captures the value.)

```
var myInt = 0

func myFunc()
{
    myInt+=1
}

print(myInt) //prints 0
myFunc()
print(myInt) //prints 1
```

I am running this in Xcode playground, could that have something to do with it?

Thanks

Comment: Actually it is not capturing the value it just changes the value of a variable

Comment: @TysonVignesh Ah, I thought capturing simply means using a variable that was declared outside the function's block.